# Making same-app windows have grouped alt-tab behaviour in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I've previously used Fedora in which an application with multiple windows will be grouped into the same tile when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>bing, and to get to separate windows you use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) combination - e.g. if Firefox has 3 windows open, you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle through these, and not <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> because they're grouped together.

I've installed Ubuntu and am sad to see this behaviour is not present. Is there a way to enable this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Found that the default key combination for this is <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> in Ubuntu.